# Certbot SSL certificate doesn't work

Tags: ssl, nginx, certbot

I've succesfully set up Nginx. My site was available via `http`. After that I've instaled certbot certificate. There were no errors while installing.

What do I have now in my config:

```
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.mydomainname.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.mydomainname.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

Entering site with `https` prefix results "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

443 port is listening.

`sudo ufw status`:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

What to do?

Comment: Does your firewall allow Nginx Full? e.g `ufw allow 'Nginx Full'`

Comment: @necko yes, thanks. I've update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not letting Nginx https traffic through your firewall.

First, give Nginx full firewall access: `sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'`. 
Remove Nginx http: `sudo ufw delete allow 'Nginx HTTP'`
This should fix your problem.